WordPress - Display page content and not custom post type with <?php the_content();?>
I have created a custom post-type with a single page that serves as a template page, the CPT are listed as expected but when I include the  to list display the page content, it displays for a post content instead
    <? while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();?>

      $args = array(
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'post_type' => 'rooms',
        );

        $the_query = new WP_Query($args);
        $categories_posts = array();

        if ($the_query->have_posts()) :
            while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post();
          //code
          <? endwhile; endif; ?>

           <?php the_content();?>

I tried to move the <?php the_content();?> above the query and it displays the content i need but it doesn't work below the query

This happens because WordPress uses a global $post variable in which it stores the information about the current post. Functions like the_content() use this $post variable to know what title to get. WP_Query::the_post() overwrites the $post variable. So after your custom loop the $post will still be set to the last rooms post. Add wp_reset_postdata() after endwhile and before endif of your custom loop to reset the $post variable to its original state.

Thanks @EmielZuurbier, this fixes it.

If <?php the_content(); ?> must be placed below the custom query, you need to reset the main query after your custom loop by adding wp_reset_postdata(); right after endwhile; endif;. This will allow <?php the_content(); ?> to display the page content instead of the custom post type content.
Here's the updated code snippet:
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<?php 
  $args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'rooms',
);
$the_query = new WP_Query($args);
$categories_posts = array();

if ($the_query->have_posts()) :
  while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post();
    // Code for custom post type content
  endwhile; 
  endif; 
  wp_reset_postdata(); // Reset after custom query
?>

<?php the_content(); ?> <!-- Displays the page content -->

<?php endwhile; ?>


I would recommend placing wp_reset_postdata() between endwhile; and endif;. The reason for it is that wp_reset_postdata() only needs to be called whenever there are any posts found and $the_query->the_post() has been called. Otherwise there would be nothing to reset.
